# What is the scale of the Celwynvian map in Pathfinder #15

Tags: pathfinder-1e, adventure-path, golarion

Pathfinder #15 includes details of a ruined forest city, Celwynvian, but no scale is provided for either map. The inferred size is quite large as the order of battle laid out has a scope that belies the map depictions.

Was any scale provided in errata or other resources I may not be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No scale is presented in The Armageddon Echo itself (print or PDF), but on the forums someone projected up from the Library of Dust size and figured the whole thing's a 2000 ft across town, and James Jacobs replied to confirm it was indeed small (though he didn't cite a scale). See [Is it just me, or is Celwynvian really small?](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2j0i7?Is-it-just-me-or-is-Celwynvian-really-small#1) on the Paizo forums.